# syntax error in verilog code ,near "<=": syntax error, unexpected <=,

Tags: verilog

I am beginner in verilog so I need your help please.
I wanted to make a code for 2 digit 7 segments decoder but there is a syntax here that I can't recognize it.

The code:

```
module segment7dec (input [5:0] bin,output [3:0] bcd0,output [3:0] bcd1);


  case (bin)
 6'd0 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end

 6'd1 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0001; end

 6'd2 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0010; end

 6'd3 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0011; end

 6'd4 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0100; end

 6'd5 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0101; end

 6'd6 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0110; end

 6'd7 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0111; end

 6'd8 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b1000; end

 6'd9 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b1001; end

6'd10 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end

6'd11 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0001; end

6'd12 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0010; end

6'd13 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0011; end

6'd14 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0100; end

6'd15 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0101; end

6'd16 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0110; end

6'd17 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b0111; end

6'd18 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b1000; end

6'd19 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0001; bcd0 <= 4'b1001; end

6'd20 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end

6'd21 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0001; end

6'd22 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0010; end

6'd23 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0011; end

6'd24 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0100; end

6'd25 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0101; end

6'd26 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0110; end

6'd27 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b0111; end

6'd28 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b1000; end

6'd29 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0010; bcd0 <= 4'b1001; end

6'd30 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end

6'd31 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0001; end

6'd32 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0010; end

6'd33 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0011; end

6'd34 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0100; end

6'd35 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0101; end

6'd36 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0110; end

6'd37 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b0111; end

6'd38 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b1000; end

6'd39 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0011; bcd0 <= 4'b1001; end

6'd40 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end

6'd41 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0001; end

6'd42 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0010; end

6'd43 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0011; end

6'd44 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0100; end

6'd45 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0101; end

6'd46 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0110; end

6'd47 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b0111; end

6'd48 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b1000; end

6'd49 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0100; bcd0 <= 4'b1001; end

6'd50 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end

6'd51 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0001; end

6'd52 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0010; end

6'd53 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0011; end

6'd54 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0100; end

6'd55 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0101; end

6'd56 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0110; end

6'd57 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b0111; end

6'd58 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b1000; end

6'd59 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0101; bcd0 <= 4'b1001; end

6'd60 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0110; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end
endcase
  endmodule
```

The reported error:

> Error: C:/modeltech64_10.1c/examples/decoder1.v(4): near "<=": syntax
>   error, unexpected <=, expecting IDENTIFIER or TYPE_IDENTIFIER

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers you may need to read this things before post .. Please edit and Increase the Post Quality to not get flagged

Comment: Use `case` in some procedural statement. Like `initial`, `always` blocks etc.

Answer (score 3):

Two main issues, assignents can be made using `assign` to wires or delcare as `reg` and place in an `initial` or `always` block. For example:

```
module segment7dec (
  input  [5:0] bin,
  output reg [3:0] bcd0,  //<-- reg type
  output reg [3:0] bcd1);
```

bcd driven by flip-flops:

```
 always @(posedge clk) begin
   case (bin)
     6'd0 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0000; end
     6'd1 : begin bcd1 <= 4'b0000; bcd0 <= 4'b0001; end
     //...
   endcase
 end
```

Or for combinatorial (note the change in assignment type):

```
 always @* begin
   case (bin)
     6'd0 : begin bcd1 = 4'b0000; bcd0 = 4'b0000; end
     6'd1 : begin bcd1 = 4'b0000; bcd0 = 4'b0001; end
     //...
   endcase
 end
```

Comment: While you were typing your answer, I was typing my near identical answer. Except I didn't spot the non-blocking assignments for combinational logic. I spend too much time doing VHDL.

Comment: Morgan,Matthew , I understand the errors now , they seem to me very silly now after I got it :D , thanks very much for your response.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems preventing you compiling this:

i) The `case` statement must be within an always block. Any similar statement (eg `if`) must be in an `always` block. If the concept of an `always` block is not familiar to you, you do need to find out about them.

```
always @(*)
case (bin)
```

ii) By default, outputs are wires. You cannot drive a `wire` from an `always` block. You can only assign to a `reg` from an `always` block. Your outputs both need to be a `reg`.

```
module segment7dec (input [5:0] bin, output reg [3:0] bcd0, output reg [3:0] bcd1);
```

Your assignments in the always block should also be "blocking", as this is combinational logic:

```
6'd0 : begin bcd1 = 4'b0000; bcd0 = 4'b0000; end
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RxS